# r Shaping samples into multiple data frames (96 well plate)

Tags: r

I'm loking to take a list of samples and fit it into a data frame of a particular size (a 96 well plate).

I have some script that will allow me to do this:

```
#some sample ids
ids <- c(LETTERS, letters)
#plate size:
n <- 96
nrow <- 8
samples <- character(n)
samples[seq_along(ids)] <- ids

samples <- matrix(samples, nrow=nrow)
colnames(samples) <- seq_len(n/nrow)
rownames(samples) <- LETTERS[seq_len(nrow)]
```

However, my `ids` list is more than 96 samples in length and I want a new 'plate' data frame to start once the first is full. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking I could somehow use arrays to fix this but realy stumped on how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function can be used to split your data into a list of plates of 96 elements each. After that’s done, you can shape each individual plate vector into a matrix as appropriate:

```
# example data
ids = paste0(LETTERS, 1 : 1000)
```

```
# Ensure that IDs fit evenly into 96 well plates and fill potential
# empty wells with dummy data.
if (length(ids) %% n != 0L) {
    ids = c(ids, rep('', n - length(ids) %% n))
}

# Which plate (1 … number of plates) does each ID belong to?
plate_ids = (seq_along(ids) - 1L) %/% n + 1L

plates = lapply(
    split(ids, plate_ids),
    matrix,
    nrow = nrow,
    dimnames = list(LETTERS[seq_len(nrow)], seq_len(n %/% nrow))
)
```

That said, consider whether a list of matrices is the most convenient format to work with: it may be better to have a higher-dimensional array of identifiers; or simply a data.frame (with additional information, such as intensity or other measurement for each well).

---

To instead generate a three-dimensional array of plates, the following code is sufficient:

```
dim = c(nrow, n %/% nrow, length(ids) %/% n)
dimnames = list(LETTERS[seq_len(nrow)], seq_len(n %/% nrow), NULL)
plates = array(ids, dim = dim, dimnames = dimnames)
```

… assuming that the `ids` were already padded to be a multiple of 96 as in my code above.

Comment: this might be a super silly question but where you have `n` in the code what is expected to be here?

Comment: @Rey I used the one from your code. Same for `nrow`.

Comment: See it was super silly! Thanks very much for your help